# How do I add different IPTC keywords to multiple images?

Tags: python, image-processing, metadata, exiftool, iptc

I have a folder containing thousands of images and each image needs a unique list of keywords added to it. I also have a table with fields showing the file path and associated list of desired keywords for each image. For example, one record might need the tags, "ORASH (a survey site code), Crew 1, Transect A Upstream, Site Layout". While the next record might need the tags, "ORWLW, Crew 2, Amphibian, Pacific Giant Salamander".

How do I iterate over each image to add the IPTC keywords to them? I'm using python 3 and the iptcinfo3 module but am willing to try other modules that may work.

Here's where I'm at now:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from iptcinfo3 import IPTCInfo

srcdir = r'E:\photos'
files = os.listdir(srcdir)

# Create a dataframe from the table containing filepaths and associated keywords.
df = pd.read_excel(r'E:\photo_info.xlsx')

# Create a dictionary with the filename as the key and the tags as the value.
references = dict(df.set_index('basename')['tags'])

for file in files:
    # Get the full filepath for each image.
    filepath = os.path.join(srcdir, file)
    # Create an object for a file that may not have IPTC data (ignore the 'Marker scan...' notification).
    info = IPTCInfo(filepath, force=True)
```

At this point, I imagined I'd use `info['keywords'] = ...` in conjunction with the 'references' dictionary to plug the keywords into the correct files. Then `info.save_as(filepath)`. I'm just not experienced enough to know how to make this work or even if it's a reasonable way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you drop the `batch-processing` tag and add `exiftool` you'll probably attract someone who can show you how to do it extremely quickly without even needing Python. A representative sample of the tags you need to add would help. I guess `exiftool` would use a CSV rather than nasty, proprietary Excel formats, so you'd need to export a CSV I think.

Comment: I'll give those updates a shot. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Example here https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=9826.0

Comment: Oh, wow. I tried exiftool today and it was incredibly easy to do exactly what I was hoping for. Problem solved! Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. Add what you did as an answer to help future readers if you'd like to. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved the table with the filenames and keywords as a .csv file where the fields and records looked like this (though the text in the 'Subject' field didn't include the quotes):

> **SourceFile, Artist, Subject**
>
> E:\photos\0048.JPG,   MARY GRAY, "YEAR2022, REQUIRED, GPS UNIT WITH
> TIME"

Because I use Jupyter Lab for other portions of this workflow, I ran this code there:

```
import os

os.system('cmd d: & exiftool -overwrite_original -sep ", " -csv="E:\photos\metadata.csv" E:\photos')
```

This opens the Windows command prompt, changes the path to the D: drive (where the exiftool.exe file was saved), invokes exiftool, sets it to overwrite the original image file rather than create a copy, defines the keyword separator in the .csv file, reads the .csv file that has the list of filenames and associated keywords, then runs it on the E:\photos directory.

Worked like a charm on about 4,000 photos!

Comment: Sadly starting a separate process has nothing to do with programming - the answer would more fit [Superuser](https://superuser.com/).